# Get count for different columns with different conditions from same table into one result table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table, action using postgresql:

```
is_jump | is_throw | is_punch
true      true        false
false     true        false
false     true        true
```

These are all booleans.

I want to get a count for each of the actions (when true) into one result table in one query:

```
is_jump_count | is_throw_count | is_punch_count
     1              3                1
```

I can get the count for one of them at the time, that's the easy part, but, how can I combine it all in one query so that I get one result table with the counts by column like shown here?

I have implemented it this way, but, I wonder if there's a better way to accomplish this given that in the end I think I'll end up with about 15 actions to track count for...:

```
SELECT a.ct is_jump, b.ct is_throw
FROM
( SELECT COUNT(*) ct FROM action WHERE is_jump=true and user_id=6 ) a,
( SELECT COUNT(*) ct FROM action WHERE is_throw=true and user_id=6 ) b;
```

Comment: Have you looked at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396498/postgresql-sql-count-of-true-values

Comment: That helped me cleanup the count of true, I use SELECT count(CASE WHEN is_jump THEN 1 END)
FROM action
where user_id=6. I am trying to combined each count into a column in the result table.

Comment: Have you tried using multiple `COUNT`s in your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filtered aggregation:

```
select count(*) filter (where is_jump) as is_jump_count,
       count(*) filter (where is_throw) as is_throw_count,
       count(*) filter (where is_punch) as is_punch_count
from the_table;
```

Comment: This page has a handy table about what dbs support `filter` functionality: [filter — Selective Aggregates](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter). Of course, postgresql is one of them.